# Extra Space added when changing screen orientation

Tags: android, android-studio, android-orientation

My app adds fragments with values to the main activity at runtime but I need to be able to change the screen orientation without losing those values. The main issue is my adding of `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` to the manifest works, but a large amount of extra space is added to the top of the app, so at either orientation after the first change, about a fourth of the screen is inaccessible white space.

activity_main.xml

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme">

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/manu_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:text="Manufacturer:"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/manu_spinner"
            android:theme="@style/SpinnerStyle"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:dropDownWidth="150dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/cell_background"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/manu_label"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        </Spinner>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/panels_container"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_below="@id/manu_spinner"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

My java code does not manipulate the view except to add fragments to a linear layout:

```
private View.OnClickListener cableListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
            PanelsFragment frag = PanelsFragment.newInstance();
            cables.add(frag);
            ft.add(R.id.panels_container, frag, Integer.toString(trans.indexOf(frag)));
            ft.commit();
        }
    };
```

Is there a way to prevent the extra space between my app bar and the scrollview, or do I need a different strategy? I did try overriding the onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState, but my methods supposedly required a higher API than my minimum of 14. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

EDIT: Due to the nature of the project, I cannot provide a picture of the issue. When the app first starts, there is almost no space between the label and spinner with "manu" id's and the app bar. However, when the screen goes from portrait to landscape, at least 60dp of inaccessible space is between the app bar and the label and spinner. I noted that the 25dp of top margin for the content view was needed otherwise its contents started behind the app bar.

Comment: My first thought is an issue with margins. Can you post a picture of the issue so we can get a better idea of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was unexpectedly solved by specifying the height, width and margins for the content view in activity_main.xml:

```
<include
    layout="@layout/content_main"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp" />
```